# Installing Office 2007 breaks Data Retrieval Services in Dashboard Designer

Tags: performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I had Office 2003 & Dashboard Designer installed. I was creating a bunch of reports in dashboard designer that started by creating a data source using Microsoft's Data Retrieval Services to connect to a SharePoint list.

I installed Office 2007 and I no longer can create a data source using Data Retrieval Services.  I reinstalled Microsoft Office 2003 Web Components, but I still do not have the option to create a report based on a data source pointing to a SharePoint list.

Do I need to install Excel 2003 or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Excel 2003 side-by-side with Office 2007 and I can now use Data Retrieval Services again.